# graphql - Is there a way to avoid re-fetching data that already exists on the client, without having to explicitly re-stitch data on the client

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-client

I have some simple associations in my database, which I fetch using the below graphql queries.

```
// MakerOrders query, performed first

maker {
  id
  orders {
    id
    customer {
      id
    }
  }
}

// MakerProducts query, performed after MakerOrders

maker {
  products {
    id
    order {
      id
      customer {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The associations are:

- Orders to Customers, One to One
- Products to Orders, One to One (can be null)

I first fetch my orders with the `MakerOrders` query.

Later in the application, I fetch my products with the `MakerProducts` query.

- Note, if a product has an order, then this order must already exist in the cache from `MakerOrders`.

I am wondering if there is a simple way to avoid unnecessarily re-fetching order fields from the server (in this case, customer), whilst still being able to associate the products to their orders, and not having to re-stitch the state together on the client.

If we naively do something like this

```
// using @apollo/client

const { data } = useQuery(MakerProducts)
```

Then the server will always do a complete re-fetch of customer (as it doesn't know that we already have them).

One solution is to remove customer from `MakerProducts`, and instead fetch it later on the client (the re-stitching approach):

```
const client = useApolloClient()

const { data } = useQuery(MakerProducts)

const products = data.maker.products.map(p => {
  const order = client.readFragment({
    id: `Order:${p.order.id}`,
    fragment: fragments.OrderFields
  })
  return { ...p, order }
})
```

I am wondering if there are any other solutions to this problem, such as getters on the client (like `product.getOrder`), as opposed to having to explicitly access fields as above. I understand graphql is just a specification so there may be nothing noted inside of that, but am open to suggestions in `@apollo/client`.

Comment: Instead of using `readFragment` in a loop, you could use one complete query with the `cache-only` strategy, after fetching `MakerProducts` without the `customer`

Comment: Awesome, that's a great suggestion, thanks @Bergi